# translate to multiple languages

Tags: translation, google-translate

I would like to get translation from one ( best - automatically detected) language to 4 different using google-translate. My idea is to wrote a html document which contain 4 frames - in one of them I can find text form and button. After click on it, Internet browser will send demand to google translate and show results in 4 frames.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Are you referring to translation of natural languages, or translation of programming languages (source-to-source compilation)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a self service, hosted service that does translations and content management for you check out Localize.js

Answer (score 0):

Google has an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/) to its translate tool that will enable you to send it some text and receive back that text translated into any language you choose.

edit: This is now a paid service

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be terribly translated. As someone that speaks English well, Russian poorly, and Spanish even more poorly, I can detect that these auto-translations never come out right.

My recommendation is to serve your page through a basic system that will allow you to respond to submitted form values. Pass in &LANG=*two country iso code* and then have your backend serve up the correct data.

Have someone that speaks both languages prepare the content for you. Then, whenever you are serving these pages, you can also conditionally adjust CSS to account for differences in format which come from difference in language length.

If you don't have those capabilities available, make 5 pages. One in English and the other 4 in the other languages. You will seriously seem retarded to anyone that speaks those languages well if you use an auto-translate. I think this is a bad idea for any kind of professional page, even if you can work out the technical issues.

-Brian J. Stinar-